# Telethon splits the group of photos

Tags: python, api, telethon, aiogram

When my bot try to resend a group of photos, it splits it into separate messages. If it is a group of photos (in Telegram), I need to resend it wholly, as a group within one message. How to fix it?

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import asyncio

Id_bot = 
Id_Group2 = 
Id_Group3 = 
Id_Group4 = 
Id_Group5 = 
api_id = ''
api_hash = ''

client = TelegramClient('none', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
    chat = await event.get_chat()
    chat_id = event.chat_id
    print(chat_id)

    # Forward only if the message is not sent in Id_Group1 to avoid an infinite loop
    if chat_id not in [Id_Group2, Id_Group3, Id_Group4, Id_Group5]:
        if event.media:
            if isinstance(event.media, list):
                # Multiple media files in a single message
                media = []
                for file in event.media:
                    media.append(await client.upload_file(file))
                await client.send_file(Id_bot, media[0], caption=event.message.message, file=media[1:])
            else:
                # Single media file
                caption = event.message.message if event.message.message else None
                await client.send_file(Id_bot, event.media, caption=caption)
        elif event.message.message:
            await client.send_message(Id_bot, event.message.message)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood how the api works.. Telegram galleries are all single messages, they're gathered by the Telegram apps to display them as a collage using the message.grouped_id which signifies if a single message is part of a group. so .media will never be a list, your conditional will never be executed.

There is a dedicated handler to deal with [`Albums`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/events.html#telethon.events.album.Album), this handler is the same as NewMessage, but it does the caching and gathering all messages into a single list.

Also, telethon already offers a way to clone a message, you don't need to handle text/media (send_message/send_file) seperately. they're dealt with by only passing them the entire `Message` object, the method will extract the caption or media and any other info and clones the message.

so your code can be written as:

```py
Id_bot = 
Id_Group2 = 
Id_Group3 = 
Id_Group4 = 
Id_Group5 = 

api_id = ''
api_hash = ''

chats_to_listen_to = [Id_Group1]

client = TelegramClient('none', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chats_to_listen_to))
async def handler(event):
    if event.grouped_id:
        return    # ignore messages that are gallery here

    await client.send_message(Id_bot, event.message)

@client.on(events.Album(chats=chats_to_listen_to))
async def handler(event):
    await client.send_file(Id_bot, event.messages)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

a little note about your other misunderstanding:

> Forward only if the message is not sent in Id_Group1 to avoid an infinite loop

*If i understood what you're implying right, This is wrong. sending something will deliver you a response by the server to your session, so, you it won't dispatch something you sent yourself through NewMessage events and cause a loop, only your other active sessions will receive it as events.*